# I am trying to to store data in SQLite database

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am trying to fixed the problem in which AdapterClass has `addOrder(String s, int qty)` method the values does not insert into `database.insert("CUS_MENU", null, ocv)` and problem also shows in this line data are not stores in sqlite database.

```
public class AdapterClass 
{
    private Context context;
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    CreateDB dbHelper;
    private static String DATABASE_TABLE=" ";   
    public AdapterClass(Context pcontext, String pDBTableName) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.context = pcontext;
        this.DATABASE_TABLE = pDBTableName;
    }

    public AdapterClass Open() throws SQLException
    {
        dbHelper=new CreateDB(context);
        database=dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;    
    }

    // To Insert Record
    public long insertquery(String[] pColumnNames, String[] pColumnValues) {

        ContentValues initialValues = createContentValues(pColumnNames,pColumnValues);
        return database.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);

    }
    // Split the sting into two parts
    public void addOrder(String s, int qty){
        ContentValues ocv = new ContentValues();
        String a[] = s.split("-");
        String price = a[1].replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");

        int total = Integer.parseInt(price)*qty;

        ocv.put("PRICE", price);
        ocv.put("NAME", a[0]);
        ocv.put("QTY", qty);
        ocv.put("TOTAL", total);
        //db=this.getWritableDatabase();
        database.insert("CUS_MENU", null, ocv);
        database.close();   
    }

    }
```

This is orderscreen class the error show in these lines `order = new AdapterClass(this)` and `order.addOrder(s,i)`. please anyone help to solve this problem.

```
public class OrderScreen extends Activity implements OnClickListener  {
TextView orderitem;
EditText Quantity,devide_quanity;
Button Place_Order;
String tempstring;
Integer i;
String s;
String quanityforsoup;
StringBuilder orderdata=null;
AdapterClass order = null;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.order_screen);

        orderitem =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.orderitem);
        Quantity =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.Quantity);
        Place_Order =(Button)findViewById(R.id.Place_Order_btn);

        order = new AdapterClass(this);
        Place_Order.setOnClickListener(this); 

        s= getIntent().getStringExtra("order");
        String a[] = s.split("-");
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        //Place_Order.setClickable(false);
        tempstring=Quantity.getText().toString();   
        i=Integer.parseInt(tempstring); 
        Toast.makeText(OrderScreen.this, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        //String  temps=s;

        //  adding the data 
        order.addOrder(s,i);
        Intent mIntent = new Intent(OrderScreen.this,MenuScreen.class);
        startActivity(mIntent);
        finish();
        orderitem.setText("You have ordered "+s);

    }
```

This is the db Helper class:

```
public class CreateDB extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
SQLiteDatabase db;
public CreateDB(Context context)
{
super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "restaurant";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String MENU= "create table CUS_MENU(_id integer primary key autoincrement, " + "" + "NAME text,"+"QTY text,"+"PRICE text,TOTAL text);";

@Override public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
{
db.execSQL(MENU);
}
}
```

Comment: Show the db helper class

Comment: Any exception stacktrace?

Comment: @laalto at com.example.myapprestaurant.OrderScreen.onClick(OrderScreen.java:55)

Comment: @BobMalooga at com.example.myapprestaurant.OrderScreen.onClick(OrderScreen.java:55)

Comment: @ BobMalooga This is the db Helper class                        public class CreateDB extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
 SQLiteDatabase db;
 public CreateDB(Context context) {
  super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
 }
 
 private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "restaurant";
 private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
 private static final String MENU= "create table CUS_MENU(_id integer primary key autoincrement, " +
   "" + "NAME text,"+"QTY text,"+"PRICE text,TOTAL text);";
 @Override
 public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
 {
  db.execSQL(MENU); 
 }
}

Answer (score 0):

in the click event write .show() to show the toast. yes the error will come there at 
order = new AdapterClass(this); you wrote the constructor to be 
 public AdapterClass(Context pcontext, String pDBTableName) 
    {
        this.context = pcontext;
        this.DATABASE_TABLE = pDBTableName;
    }
then you have pass context and table name to that.
check your code once even thogh you wrote intent to move to other activity ...you are writing finish().
check and good luck